# Execution of endswith function

Tags: python, python-2.7

It seems like if statement doesn't execute or may be because i have made some mistake.

I tried,

```
ends = line.endswith('/')

if (line.startswith('  ') and ends == True)
```

But doesn't work. If statement doesn't run

```
count = 0
for line in f1:
    if (line.startswith('  ') and line.endswith('/')):
        count = count + 1
        continue

    elif line.startswith(('  ', ' ', '//')):
        continue
    else:
        if (count == 0):
            f2.write(line)
            count = 0
```

If line starts with '//' or single or double spaces, those lines should not be printed (condition 1). Also, if a line starts with double space and ends with '/' and next line doesn't satisfy condition 1, it should no be printed. Lines without condition 1 must be printed

**Input:**

```
//abcd

  abcd/

This line should not be printed

This has to be printed
```

**Expected Output:**

```
This has to be printed
```

**Actual output:**

```
This line should not be printed

This has to be printed
```

Comment: You seem to be missing code. What are `f1` and `f2`?

Comment: `if (count == 0):` you do stuff and set `count` to 0, what's the point, count is already 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines generated by iterating through a file object always end with a newline character (unless it's the last line of the file and the file does not end with a trailing newline character). You can apply `rstrip` to the line before you use `endswith` to test if a line ends with a certain character. Also, you should reset `counter` (with `count = 0`) outside of the `if (count == 0):` block; otherwise the statement would never run:

```
from io import StringIO
f1 = StringIO('''//abcd
  abcd/
This line should not be printed
This has to be printed
''')
f2 = StringIO()
count = 0
for line in f1:
    if (line.startswith('  ') and line.rstrip().endswith('/')):
        count = count + 1
    elif not line.startswith(('  ', ' ', '//')):
        if (count == 0):
            f2.write(line)
        count = 0
print(f2.getvalue())
```

This outputs:

```
This has to be printed
```